# Difference between `zero(eltype(x))` and `zero(x)` in Julia

Tags: julia

In 'Julia High Performance' (2nd Ed.), the author gives the following example to explain how to obtain type stability in loops:

```
function simdsum_fixed(x)
    s = zero(eltype(x))
    @simd for v in A
        s += v
    end
    return s
end
```

In a previous example, with different code they simply use `zero(x)`. I've therefore tried the same function without `eltype()` as below (`simdsum_fixed_b`). They seem to work in the same way.

```
function simdsum_fixed_b(x)
    s = zero(x)
    @simd for v in A
        s += v
    end
    return s
end
```

How is then `zero(eltype(x))` different from `zero(x)`? What is the advantage of using the first over the second?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason your function shows the same behaviour in both cases is probably that you are initializing with `zero(x)`, but iterating over a different variable, `A`, which is probably a global variable. If you fix this mistake, your second example should fail if you input a vector, `x`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `zero(eltype(x))` if `x` is a container (e.g. a vector) and you want additive identity of its elements. Use `zero(x)` if you want to get the additive identity of `x` itself.

Example with vector as here the difference is most clearly visible:

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> zero(x)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 0
 0

julia> zero(eltype(x))
0
```